# Как создать динамический трехмерный массив и заполнить его случайными значениями?

Tags: c, c++, visual-c++

Я больше по Java, но сейчас надо сделать пару задачек по плюсам. Одна из них звучит как-то так:

> Введя значения m,n,r, определить
> трехмерный массив P = размерами i,j,k,
> где i=1,n;j=1,m;k=1,r. Значения
> элементов которого определяются
> случайно.

Упустим тот момент, что преподаватель не знает, что в плюсах массив считается с нуля...
С malloc/free не работал в плюсах, а тем более с трехмерными массивами, так что понятия не имею, как это делается. Надо использовать malloc/free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Трехмерный массив можно представить как правильный многогранник или же двумерные массивы, уложенные по слоям.

[image]
<sub>(источник: [convdocs.org](http://kk.convdocs.org/pars_docs/refs/170/169229/169229_html_m7ce0a59d.gif))</sub>

Соответственно легче ориентироваться как в декартовой системе координат, проставив оси X,Y,Z на соответствующих направлениях. Сначала создаются слои, от ближнего к дальнему:

```
int ***arr = new int**[zindex];
```

Ну а каждый из слоев, это просто обычный уже двумерный массив. Получается такая ссылка на массив двумерных массивов. Остается выделить память под строки и столбцы для каждого слоя.

```
for(int i=0; i<zindex; i++){
    arr[i] = new int*[yindex]; //выделяем память на столбцы

    for(int j=0; j<yindex;j++){
        arr[i][j] = new int[xindex]; //выделяем память на строки.
    }
}
```

Вот в общем-то и все, остается только заполнить рандомными числами. Полный пример(если я нигде не намудрил с памятью):

```
int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");

    int zindex = 10, yindex = 5, xindex = 7;

    int ***arr = new int**[zindex];

    for(int i=0; i<zindex; i++){
        arr[i] = new int*[yindex];

        for(int j=0; j<yindex;j++){
            arr[i][j] = new int[xindex];
        }
    }

    for(int z=0;z<zindex;z++)
        for(int y=0;y<yindex;y++)
            for(int x=0;x<xindex;x++)
                arr[z][y][x] = rand();

    for(int z=0;z<zindex;z++)
        for(int y=0;y<yindex;y++)
            for(int x=0;x<xindex;x++)
                cout << arr[z][y][x] << endl;

    system("pause");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Учитывая, что malloc/free практически ничем не отличаются в плане выделения памяти(вообще это сишный вариант выделения памяти), стоит только заменить new на его эквивалент. Вот тут не уверен, но возможно это будет выглядеть так:

```
arr = (int ***) malloc(zindex*sizeof(int**)); 
for (i = 0; i < zindex; i++) {
    arr[i] = (int **) malloc(yindex*sizeof(int*));
    for(j = 0; j < yindex; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = (int *) malloc(xindex*sizeof(int));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, как другие компиляторы, а gcc (но не g++) позволяет передавать в функцию размерности измерений матрицы в ее аргументах.

Это позволяет не моделировать 2-х и 3-х мерные массивы, как показал в своем ответе [@Alex Krass](/users/16416/alex-krass) массивами указателей, а выделить одну последовательную область памяти нужного размера и разместить многомерный массив в ней. Т.е. практически так же, как делает компилятор, когда размер каждого измерения известен при компиляции (константа).

Вот пример:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void
rfill (int n, int m, int r, int a[n][m][r], int d)
{
  srand(time(0)); // выбросьте, если хотите повторяемости результата в разных запусках

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
      for (int k = 0; k < r; k++)
        a[i][j][k] = rand() % d;
}

void
print (int n, int m, int r, int a[][m][r]) // а старшую размерность можно опустить !!!
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("slice %d\n", i);
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < r; k++)
        printf ("%5d ", a[i][j][k]);
      puts("");
    }
  }
}

int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int n, m, r, nn;
  scanf("%d %d %d", &n, &m, &r);
  nn = n * m * r;
  printf("size %d (%dx%dx%d)\n", nn, n, m, r);
  int *a = malloc(sizeof(*a) * nn);

  rfill(n, m, r, (int (*)[m][r])a, 1000);
  print(n, m, r, (int (*)[m][r])a);
}
```

Обратите внимание на **приведение  типа** при передаче указателя в функции.

Транслируем (ключ -std=c99 нужен исключительно для описаний индексов в стиле C++) и запускаем

```
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ gcc -std=c99 c.c
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ ./a.out
2 3 4
size 24 (2x3x4)
slice 0
  819   953   252   669 
  287   460     8   582 
  154   112   346   220 
slice 1
  385   608   815   953 
  333   808   582   233 
  304   746   445   773 
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$
```

Возможно, это не то, что хотел преподаватель, но как и многое в GNU достаточно практично.

Конечно, можно и **просто моделировать обращения к элементам такой матрицы, самостоятельно вычисляя адрес нужного элемента**.

Добавим в конец `main()` вот такой код:

```
  printf ("Enter i, j, k: "); fflush(stdout);
  int i, j, k;
  scanf("%d %d %d", &i, &j, &k);

  printf ("%d\n", a[i * m * r + j * r + k]);
```

и в результате увидим:

```
....
slice 1
  215   877   552   933 
  458   501   568   727 
  485   975   235    39 
Enter i, j, k: 1 1 3
727
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$
```

Надеюсь, что все это достаточно интересно.